# Kadish at the end of Davening

Tags: halacha, tefilla, kaddish

When I am a Shliach Tzibur, and there are no mourners, should I say Kadish at the end of davening? I know there is an opinion in the Shulchan Aruch that says that davening ends with Kadish. Does anyone know where in the Shulchan Aruch that is? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

*Orach Chaim* (132,2) in *Rema* writes that the *Kadish Yasom* is reserved for a *yasom* (i.e.one mourning a parent first 11 months). However, if there is no *yasom* anyone without a father and mother should say it and even one with parents can say it if his parents don't mind his saying that *Kadish*.

Comment: I learnt that someone with parents who wishes to say Kadish Yasom must have their permission first.